# convert seconds in list of dictionaries into hours, python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, datetime, seconds

I'm trying to convert the seconds in my list of dictionaries into hours using the DateTime package from python. Eg.g instead of 'Duration': 745200 (seconds) I want 'Duration': 207:00:00 (hours:minutes:seconds). Could someone help me with how to achieve this?
Thank you!

```
id_duration = 
[{'Id': 44, 'Duration': 745200},
 {'Id': 45, 'Duration': 259200},
 {'Id': 58, 'Duration': 21600},
 {'Id': 61, 'Duration': 597600}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all start by importing the package

```
import datetime
```

Then let's define a function for that, using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
def convert_duration(duration_list):
    for i in duration_list:
        i['Duration'] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=i['Duration'])
        i['Duration'] = i['Duration'].total_seconds()
        i['Duration'] = i['Duration'] / 3600
    return duration_list
```

Now let's test using the example you give

```
id_duration = [{'Id': 44, 'Duration': 745200}, {'Id': 45, 'Duration': 259200}, {'Id': 58, 'Duration': 21600}, {'Id': 61, 'Duration': 597600}]

print(convert_duration(id_duration))

[Out]: [{'Id': 44, 'Duration': 207.0}, {'Id': 45, 'Duration': 72.0}, {'Id': 58, 'Duration': 6.0}, {'Id': 61, 'Duration': 166.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just hours, you can try naive approach without DateTime package:

```
[{**x, "Duration": x["Duration"] // 3600} for x in id_duration]
```